# Identify date at beginning of a string

Tags: python, regex, date

I have strings with a date at the beginning. I want to remove the date from the string.

**The date could be in various formats**, and I don't know it previously (anyway I can decide to manually select the more common of them, such as dd-mm-yyy, dd-mm, dd/mm,...).

I need to extract and store the substring that is after the date.

**EXAMPLE**:

For example I have the following sentences and the desidera output:

*02/01/2019* The UK prime minister -> The UK prime minister

*02-01-2019* The UK prime minister -> The UK prime minister

The UK prime minister in *02/01/2019* -> The UK prime minister in *02/01/2019*

*02-01-2019 18:52:02* The UK prime minister -> The UK prime minister

I think that Regex could be a good option, but actually I am not able to figure the problem with regex. Also other methods are welcome!

Comment: If the format changes, I think the best course of action could be to extract every non letter character until it hits the first letter character.  Something like `[^a-zA-z]+(.*)`

Comment: Does [`^(?=[\d/-]{5,}\s)\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{2}(?:\d{2})?\s`](https://regex101.com/r/0gOvfQ/1) work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to remove the various date formats you mentioned,

```
^(?:\d{2}[/-]){2}\d{4}(?:\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\b)?
```

**[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/70Imof/1)**

In case you want to support more formats where it is like `2019-10-22` where year comes first, you can use this enhanced regex,

```
^(?:\d{2,4}[/ -]){2}\d{2,4}(?:\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\b)?
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/70Imof/3/)

Sample Python code demo,

```
import re

arr = ['02/01/2019 The UK prime minister','02-01-2019 The UK prime minister','The UK prime minister in 02/01/2019','02-01-2019 18:52:02 The UK prime minister','2019-01-02 The UK prime minister','2019/01/02 The UK prime minister','2019 01 02 The UK prime minister','2019-01-02 18:52:02 The UK prime minister','2019/01/02 18:52:02 The UK prime minister','2019 01 02 The UK prime minister']

for s in arr:
 print(s, '-->', re.sub(r'^(?:\d{2,4}[/ -]){2}\d{2,4}(?:\s+(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\b)? ?', '', s))
```

Prints,

```
02/01/2019 The UK prime minister --> The UK prime minister
02-01-2019 The UK prime minister --> The UK prime minister
The UK prime minister in 02/01/2019 --> The UK prime minister in 02/01/2019
02-01-2019 18:52:02 The UK prime minister --> The UK prime minister
2019-01-02 The UK prime minister --> The UK prime minister
2019/01/02 The UK prime minister --> The UK prime minister
2019 01 02 The UK prime minister --> The UK prime minister
2019-01-02 18:52:02 The UK prime minister --> The UK prime minister
2019/01/02 18:52:02 The UK prime minister --> The UK prime minister
2019 01 02 The UK prime minister --> The UK prime minister
```

Comment: Great! How can I use it in Python in order to replace the date with an empty char?

Comment: @AndreaM: Added some sample codes. Let me know if you have any issues further.

Comment: What about date such as 5/02/2019? It seems to fail because it expect two digits for the first slot. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: @AndreaM: Very easy to fix. If you want to allow even 1 digit as month or day, just change `{2}` to `{1,2}` and `{2,4}` to `{1,4}` [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/70Imof/4)

Comment: I modified it as follows: ^(?:\d{1,4}[/ -]){1,2}\d{1,4}(?:\s+(?:\d{1,2}:){1,2}\d{1,2}\b)? ?  .... I modified also the {2,4} in {1,4}. Do you thing it is right?

Comment: @AndreaM: Check my demo, you only need to extend the `\d{2,4}` to `\d{1,4}`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need replacing with an empty char to remove the date. I'm assuming your input as a list. So you can try this: [RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/CtEdDR/2)

```
import re

mylist = ["02/01/2019 The UK prime minister",
          "02-01-2019 The UK prime minister",
          "The UK prime minister in 02/01/2019",
          "02-01-2019 18:52:02 The UK prime minister"]

for d in mylist:
    regex = re.search("[0-9\/\-\:\s]+(\w.*)",d)
    regex = regex.groups()[0]
    print (regex)
```